# Ember uglify breaks rainbow.js

Tags: ember.js, bower, rainbow-js

I am trying to add rainbow code samples to my ember project. I installed rainbow through bower and it works locally. However when I build and deploy to staging I am getting JS console errors.

[image: source error]

As far as I can tell this is the minified version of [this](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/blob/master/src/worker.js#L6). It appears to me that for some reason the Prism class is not being included when it is minified. I am importing

```
    'rainbow/dist/rainbow.min.js',
    'rainbow/src/language/generic.js',
    'rainbow/src/language/r.js',
    'rainbow/src/language/python.js',
    'rainbow/src/language/json.js',
    'rainbow/src/language/html.js'
```

in my ember-cli-build.js using

`bowerDependencies.forEach(function(path) { app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/' + path); });`.

If I build with minify off it works wonderfully, but I would like to minify the JS. I am currently at a loss of why these files are not being included.

Answer (score 0):

Use `./rainbow/dist/rainbow.min.js` for al the file inclusion.

Refer :
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6829

Comment: I am pretty sure that is saying the opposite no? also I am including all these using  
`bowerDependencies.forEach(function(path) {
    app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/' + path);
  });`

If I change the import path it cannot find `Rainbow` at all

Comment: You are using app.bowerDirectory so ignore my answer